# Convert float-type column values to integer-type if the value has no decimal value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, floating-point, type-conversion

This is my code

```
$data = DB::table('constructor_standings')
    ->join('constructors', 'constructors.constructorId', '=', 'constructor_standings.constructorId')
    ->select('constructor_standings.*', 'constructors.*')
    ->where(['constructor_standings.raceId' => $res2])
    ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
    ->get();

return $data;
```

In *constructor_standings* there is a column *"points"*. The column's type is float. Although only few values are decimal so I want the rest of them to be returned as integer and not as a number `.0` float.

I am using Laravel5.8. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a number is a decimal by first checking if it's numeric (just in case), and then rounding it down and comparing the rounded down number to the original number. If it's the same, it's not a decimal number.

```
is_numeric($originalNumber) && floor($originalNumber) != $originalNumber
```

You could try something like this before your return:

```
$data = array_map(function ($value) {
    $value["points"] = is_numeric($value["points"]) && floor($value["points"]) != $value["points"] ? $value["points"] : intval($value["points"]);
    return $value;
}, $data->toArray());
```

What this little piece of code does is for every item in $data, it checks if the "points" index has a decimal. If it does, then it puts the value back as an integer. If it doesn't, it returns the original value from the "points" index.

Comment: array_map(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given. Although i can try some solutions based on that logic

Comment: If you're okay with using an array instead of a collection you can use $data->toArray()

Comment: Collections have a `map` method

Answer (score 0):

Within a chained `map()` call, determine if the `point` property has no decimal places by calling `!fmod()` with the point value divided by `1`.  If the result is `0`, then you can explicitly cast the float-type value to an int-type value without any data loss.

```
return DB::table('constructor_standings')
    ->join('constructors', 'constructors.constructorId', '=', 'constructor_standings.constructorId')
    ->select('constructor_standings.*', 'constructors.*')
    ->where(['constructor_standings.raceId' => $res2])
    ->orderBy('position', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->map(function($row) {
        if (!fmod($row->point, 1)) {
            $row->point = (int) $row->point;
        }
        return $row;
    });
```